# Use date range from Excel cells in SQL data connection

Tags: sql-server, excel, cell, lookup, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a spreadsheet which pulls data in via a SQL query, when I pass this to a user I want them to be able to change the date range in the spreadsheet itself rather than in the SQL connection string.

Currently I have this:

```
WHERE     
    (new_attendedBase.CreatedBy = '1fa51434-633e-a395-000c29484a59') 
    AND (new_attendedBase.new_ActivityDate > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-11-01 00:00:00', 102) 
    AND new_attendedBase.new_ActivityDate < CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-12-01 00:00:00', 102))
```

But what I would like to do is remove the hard coded dates `2016-12-01 00:00:00` and replace with a cell reference `[sheet1$b$9]`.

I suspect its the `CONVERT` function which is causing the issue but my very limited SQL skills means I am unsure how to remove this and still allow the query to work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What actual **database** are you talking about? SQL is just the query language - that doesn't tell us whether you're using `oracle`, `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server` or `db2` or something else entirely - please add a relevant tag

Comment: Apologies, it is connecting to a Microsoft CRM 2013 instalation whose data is stored in SQL-Server. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have found to do this is to build your query string and then change the data connection properties via VBA.  You can reference your cell values using `Range("A1").Text`

You can set the `CommandText` value using the following VBA code:

```
Dim MyStr As String
MyStr = "<Your Query Here>"

With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("<Your Connection Name Here>").OLEDBConnection
   .CommandText = Array(MyStr)
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("<Your Connection Name Here>").Refresh
```

Once you have your function set up, you can call it on the click of a button in your worksheet.